# How to name dataframe with variables in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to generate multiple `DataFrames` in Pandas?
I want to name the `DataFrames` with variables like:

```
for i in range　1 to 100
dfi in dfs


df1=
df2=
df3=

:
:
:

df99=
df100=
```

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use `dict comprehension`:

```
N = 101 # 5 in sample
dfs = {'name' + str(i):df for i in range(1,N)}
print (dfs)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

N = 5
dfs = {'name' + str(i):df for i in range(1,N)}
print (dfs)
{'name3':    A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3, 'name4':    A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3, 'name2':    A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3, 'name1':    A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3}

print (dfs['name1'])
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3
```

Comment: I was going to do several including yours.  but I don't like this question.. so I'm going to delete my answer

Comment: Thanks! That makes here a great place!

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to create named variables, you can do the following

```
variables = locals()
for i in range(100):
    variables["df{0}".format(i)] = ...
```

But as others suggested, using a dictionary is perhaps better